# Create windows user with chef and add user to the local Administrators group

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

Chef documentation for the user resource: http://docs.getchef.com/resource_user.html

Doing this works:

```
user "TestUser" do
  password "p@ssw0rd"
end
```

But when I add a gid it fails:

```
user "TestUser" do
  password "p@ssw0rd"
  gid "Administrators"
end
```

I've also tried passing .\Administrator, but get the same result:

```
[2014-08-08T14:00:11-07:00] FATAL: ArgumentError: user[TestUser] (test::users line 11) had an error: ArgumentError: The user does not belong to this group.
```

Is the purpose of gid not to specify group membership?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eventually figured it out. The trick is to modify the group like so:

```
user "TestUser" do
  password "p@ssw0rd"
end

group "Administrators" do
  action :modify
  members "TestUser"
  append true
end
```